# How to trigger javascript function in webview flutter?

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

Trying to convert old code for webview plugin 3 to 4, but stuck on how to transfer message back to webpage.

Below is the function that trigger the receivePhoto() function in webpage, but somehow it does not trigger (the jsCode is shown in terminal).

```
void _pickfile() async {
  final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  if (pickedFile != null) {
    final bytes = await pickedFile.readAsBytes();
    final base64 = base64Encode(bytes);
    final jsCode = "receivePhoto('$base64');";
    await WebViewController().runJavaScript(jsCode);
    print(jsCode);//this print works
  } else {
    // User canceled the picker
  }
}
```

This is the main code:

```
class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<WebViewApp> createState() => _WebViewAppState();
}


class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {
  WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
    ..enableZoom(false)

    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)

    ..addJavaScriptChannel('FileInputChannel', onMessageReceived: (message) async {
      if (message.message == 'pickFile') {
        _pickfile();
      }
    })

    ..loadRequest(
      Uri.parse("https://youtube.com"),
    );


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I get the answer by myself and going to share here.

The problem is due to the controller cannot be state again in initialize stage, so, just create the instance(controller) before initialize it.
*using _controller which seem clearer

```
class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {
  late final WebViewController _controller;//initialize here first

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initWebViewController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: WebViewWidget(controller: _controller),
        ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    final pickedFile =
    await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      final bytes = await pickedFile.readAsBytes();
      final base64 = base64Encode(bytes);
      final jsCode = "receivePhoto('$base64');";
      await _controller.runJavaScript(jsCode);
      print(jsCode);
    }
  }

  void _initWebViewController() {
    _controller = WebViewController()
      ..enableZoom(false)

      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)

      ..addJavaScriptChannel('FileInputChannel', onMessageReceived: (message) async {
        if (message.message == 'pickFile') {
          _pickImage();
        }
      })

      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
             //progress bar
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
          },
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )

      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse(url),//url = your initial url
      );
  }
}
```